# Postfix handling Amazon SES Maximum Send Rate error

Tags: postfix-mta, amazon-ses

We have a postfix server which we were using to send emails. This server is used by many services. Thus for using Amazon SES, I've integrated our postfix server with SES SMTP interface ( using "http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html" ). The configuration is working fine and mails are getting delivered properly.

Now, there is a limit of 5 email/sec, imposed by SES and it raises error '**454 Throttling failure: Maximum sending rate exceeded** ' if limit exceeds.

I'm a newbie to Postfix.
Kindly guide me with the configuration settings in Postfix to make postfix resend the mail when error '454 Throttling failure: Maximum sending rate exceeded' occurs.

Also, how to resend email, when occasionally '**Connection timed out**' error occurs with relay server(Amazon SES).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the actual answer you are asked,but you can bypass the issue with this,

You can add this lines in main.cf file

default_destination_concurrency_limit=1
default_destination_rate_delay=10s

This will increase the time delay but you don't get the error message.

You can also verify this [link](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html) to learn more about postfix performance turning

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing so I tried it out on a fresh postfix install. I found that no additional configuration was required and postfix did indeed retry sending the messages about 5 minutes after original throttling error was reported in the log file.